# Concurrency in Azure DataFactory

Tags: concurrency, azure-data-factory, databricks, orchestration

I have an Azure Data Factory Pipeline where it has 24 parallel jobs : databricks notebooks.
In the Pipeline configuration I set concurrency to 4 but when I run the Pipeline the 24 jobs start to run in parallel although I want just 4 of them to start running in the first place. 
According to the documentation [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/data-factory/v1/data-factory-scheduling-and-execution.md) , I can run 4 parallel jobs and the others will be in queued status. 
am I missing another paramater to configure ?
[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The link which you are following is for ADF v1 , it clearly mention's that on top of the doc . The feature which you are trying to use is for adf v2 .

"[!NOTE] This article applies to version 1 of Data Factory. If you are using the current version of the Data Factory service, see pipeline execution and triggers article."

Comment: aah I didn't pay attention to that. Thank you so much for the answer. I was checking the documentation for pipeline execution and triggers. I found the parameter concurrency in the Tumbling window trigger. Do you think that can help me control how many parallel jobs I can trigger within one pipeline ?